# How does current divide in a conductor?

Tags: electric-current

If you have a cylindrical current carrying wire and you divide it into many smaller wires, will the current in those wires remain the same or get divided in some ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are probably confused about what electric current is.

If current were the speed at which electrons flow through the wire, they would have the same speed if you divided the thick wire into many thinner wires. The "current" would be the same in the thin wires as it is in the thick wire.

But current is actually the number of electrons flowing per second past any point in a circuit. The thinner wires will carry fewer electrons, because the total number of electrons flowing through all the thin wires must add up to the number flowing through the thick wire. So the current through each thinner wire is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that the cylindrical wire even after being cut has the same electric field across their ends. We denote the set of divided wires as $ S = (x_i) $.In this case, the current density through any $x_i \in S$ is given by$ \vec J = \sigma \vec E$ where $\sigma$ denotes the conductivity of the wires(same for all $x_i \in S$, as their material is same). Clearly, the current density is the same for all the wires. Thus the current through any one of them is given by $I = \int_{a_i} \vec  J . da$ where the integral is over the crossection $ a_i of the wire x_i}.

To conclude, the current distribution will depend on the conssection of each cut wire, given the material and emf remains the same.